# SATA M.2 drive on non NVMe enabled bios

Tags: boot, bios, sata, nvme, m.2

Can you boot a SATA M.2 drive from old mainboard?

The thing is, that I don't use this SATA M.2 anymore for my drive, and wanted to put it to my NAS box.
But I know for sure, that my NAS box doesn't support NVMe, yet. No NVMe slot whatsoever. I can buy an adapter, but I need to make sure before I proceed that my BIOS will be able to boot from it.

The M.2 card that I need to move is Samsung 850 Evo M.2 SATA3. As for NAS box, it is a repurposed old AMD AM3 mainboard. Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3 (rev 4.1). UEFI is supported, but no NVMe as of yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The adapter or card you purchase would have to support booting, and the main board would have to support booting to that device. A normal, old, desktop computer board won't likely offer this function.

Answer (score 0):

The key part here is that your M.2 drive is a **SATA** one, not NVMe.

In this case, the only thing you'll need is a connector adapter that can convert the unified M.2 connector into separate SATA power and data connectors. For example, this [Delock product #62559](https://www.delock.de/produkte/G_62559/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en) should work.

Since the drive has a regular SATA interface, once the connector incompatibility is solved, it should behave just like a regular SATA SSD - also for booting.

[This picture from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#/media/File:SATA_Express_interface.svg) describes the three possible methods for using a M.2 connector for storage. Since your drive is definitely not a NVMe drive, the blue "SATA Express/NVM Express" path does not apply to you.

As far as I understand, your case would be described by the red "Legacy SATA" path. In this case, a simple connector adapter can do the job just fine.

The only possible problem would be if the drive was designed to use the yellow "SATA Express/AHCI" path. In other words, these drives connect to the PCIe part of the M.2 interface, but then provide their own AHCI SATA controller on-board. I haven't seen these for sale anywhere. You would need these only if you had a M.2 slot with no SATA connectivity - and I've never seen such a slot.

I'm guessing the yellow path has in practice turned out to be a very rare special case. It's more expensive to manufacture than the "Legacy SATA" case, and still has the performance disadvantages of SATA, so I can see why the manufacturers would want to avoid the yellow path.

(Some motherboards have M.2 slots with SATA connectivity *only*, and these can only take the "Legacy SATA" style M.2 drives. These tend to be the earliest adopters of M.2 or low-end motherboards that prominently proclaim the M.2 slot but don't mention NVMe at all.)

Comment: Thank you.. Yes.. the key part here is that mine is SATA, not a real NVMe drive. So, I think I have to bit the bullet and see then. Will test it out, and will accept the relevant answer.